# mysql retrieve field names as part of recordset

Tags: mysql, field

I have an application where I must avoid any processing of a MySQL recordset returned from a SELECT query, since interacting with the return in any way results in expensive VBA operations (which crashes MS Excel for large data returns).  Instead I pass the recordset directly to a cell range.  This requires that the recordset be formatted and sorted by the data server.

I would like my select query to return a recordset, the first row of which is the list of fields.  I find myself doing something like this

```
(SELECT 'ticker', 'name', 'revenue', 'eps')
UNION
(SELECT ticker, name, revenue, EPS, FROM table
WHERE ticker IN
('BLK','DOV','ESL','CSCO','FB','AME','AXP','BAC','BEAV','EL','MMM','IBM'))
ORDER BY 
FIELD(ticker, 'ticker','BLK','DOV','ESL','CSCO','FB','AME','AXP','BAC','BEAV','EL','MMM','IBM')
```

which feels a little bit ridiculous.  Is there really no MySQL built-in function to return field names as a record?

Comment: They are returned as metadata. You want them to be part of your returned records instead? That is unusual. Usually you just let the data in excel return below a static header (so in A2 instead of cell A1)

Comment: When I read the title of this question, your "ridiculous" approach was what I intended to propose as a solution. Well, I would include an extra field and an extra level of a derived query to allow an ORDER BY to keep the header row on top. I'll be curious to see if there's a better way.

Comment: Understood.  Thanks.  Perhaps the requirement of putting metadata in the recordset is more exotic than I first thought.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the columns from a table like so:

```
SHOW COLUMNS FROM mytable FROM mydb;
```

> SHOW COLUMNS displays the following values for each table column:
>
> Field indicates the column name.
>
> Type indicates the column data type.
>
> Collation indicates the collation for nonbinary string columns, or
>   NULL for other columns. This value is displayed only if you use the
>   FULL keyword.
>
> The Null field contains YES if NULL values can be stored in the
>   column. If not, the column contains NO as of MySQL 5.0.3, and ''
>   before that.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-columns.html

There are ways of formatting this with your application layer